# phpMyAdmin - Error The json extension is missing

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have installed on Ubuntu PHP, MySQL, apache and phpmyadmin. When I try to open via browser phpmyadmin I got this error

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>
> The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

There are a lot of similar thread and I have tried a lot of solutions provided in them but none is helped me to fix this issue. Firstly I tried to install this extension like `sudo apt-get install php5-json` and this is the result

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-json is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
javascript-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So obviously I have the latest version of php5-json - `php5-json is already the newest version.`
This is my version of Ubuntu

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

But I have no idea how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check last message from this link: [Ubuntu Forum Thread: dpkg: javascript-common error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232128)

Next install "javascript-common" package, next json package.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've removed `javascript-common` and installed it again. Now I don't have error for javascript but still can't run `phpmyadmin`..

Comment: As long with "The json extension is missing" ?

Comment: I've removed `phpmyadmin` then installed it again and made steps in the link you provide me and now is working. Thank's